# How to calculate the limit $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sqrt 2 \frac {\Gamma\left(\frac {n+1} 2\right)} {\Gamma\left(\frac {n} 2\right)}-\sqrt n$

Tags: gamma-distribution

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sqrt 2 \frac {\Gamma\left(\frac {n+1} 2\right)} {\Gamma\left(\frac {n} 2\right)}-\sqrt n$$

It seems that using Stirling approximation doesn't work.

Comment: Do you know the functional equation for $\Gamma$?

Comment: The searched limit is zero.

Comment: I used this formula $\Gamma(z+1) \sim \sqrt{2 \pi z}\left(\frac{z}{e}\right)^{z}$. Is this not Stirling's approximation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need Stirling's approximation, but it *has* to work.

Let $r(n)=\Gamma((n+1)/2)/\Gamma(n/2)$. Since 
$$ \Gamma(\alpha)=\int_{0}^{+\infty} x^{\alpha}\frac{dx}{xe^x} $$
the $\Gamma$ function is log-convex on $\mathbb{R}^+$, hence $r(n)$ is an increasing function. We have
$$ r(n)^2\leq r(n)r(n+1) = \frac{n}{2} \leq r(n+1)^2 $$
from which $\sqrt{2}\,r(n) = \sqrt{n}+o(1)$ can be easily deduced.

Comment: Thank you! I finally find Strling's approximation really works. I was careless.

Comment: @Downvoter: please explain your downvote.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\lim_{n \to \infty}\braces{\root{2}\,
{\Gamma\pars{\bracks{n + 1}/2} \over \Gamma\pars{n/2}} - \root{n}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{\root{2}\,
{\pars{n/2 - 1/2}! \over \pars{n/2 - 1}!} - \root{n}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{\root{2}\,
{\root{2\pi}\pars{n/2 - 1/2}^{n/2}\expo{-n/2 + 1/2} \over \root{2\pi}\pars{n/2 - 1}^{n/2 - 1/2}\expo{-n/2 + 1}} - \root{n}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{\root{2}\,
{\pars{n/2}^{n/2}\,\pars{1 - 1/n}^{n/2} \over
\pars{n/2}^{n/2 - 1/2}\pars{1 - 2/n}^{n/2 - 1/2}}\,\expo{-1/2} - \root{n}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\lim_{n \to \infty}\pars{\root{2}\root{n \over 2}
{\expo{-1/2} \over \expo{-1}}\,\expo{-1/2} - \root{n}} =
 \bbx{\large 0}
\end{align}